# testing FOSUserBundle UnitTest

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'am trying to run fosuserbundle unit test using this cmd :

```
phpunit vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Tests/Model/UserTest.php
```

but it generates an error :

```
FOS\UserBundle\Tests\Model\UserTest::testUsername PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_RuntimeException: Class "FOS\UserBundle\Model\User" does not exist.
```

so this specific mock function : `$this-getMockForAbstractClass('FOS\UserBundle\Model\User');` isn't working any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: add the code that you have tried so far

Comment: i didn't write any code i am trying to run fosuserbundle own unit tests

Comment: then this is not the SE for you, you might get help in super user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide for PHPUnit a bootstrap file. Otherwise it doesn't have autoloaders which will find classes.

For Symfony you can use `app/autoload.php` file.

For more information about PHPUnit's bootstrap file please refer to [their site](https://phpunit.de/getting-started.html).

Answer (score 0):

actually to make it work with symfony all i needed was to add this option to my command `-c app` wish refer to my app folder that will call auto loader .

Full cmd : `phpunit --stop-on-error --stop-on-failure -c app <your-test-location>`